# Render a partial as a layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is is possible to render a partial as a layout?

Currently, I have a partial `_show.html.erb` under `app/views/users`. In some other controllers, I tried to include `layout 'users/show'` to use that partial as a layout.

Yet, by default, Rails seems to be looking for layouts in `layouts/` directory. And I get such error as:

```
Template is missing

Missing template layouts/users/show ....
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're right, the layout method only looks in the layouts folder. I'd suggest using a partial instead. Why do you need a layout instead of a partial?

Comment: @sealocal Thanks for your answer. I want to yield one view file inside another view file (the partial).

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I'd recommend reading "[Understanding yield](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#structuring-layouts) in the Rails Guides if you haven't already. As you said, `layout` searches the `layouts` folder, and `yield` is replaced with the view that is called by the controller action. `yield` can also return a content block, but not a partial.

Comment: @sealocal Thanks for the suggestion. But I kind of figured out the way. I rendered a partial as a layout in a view file, and passed in blocks, which is then yielded inside the partial.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you just want to include a partial in another view you should user `render`:

```
<%= render partial: 'users/show' %>
```

Perhaps in your other controller's action you have:

```
@user = @some_object.user
```

You'll need to pass in the `@user` to your partial. You might want to refer to a local variable, `user`, in your `users/show` partial and pass in the instance variable:

```
<%= render partial: 'users/show', locals: {user: @user} %>
```

You can also use the partial and layout options to together so that a partial will render inside a specified layout. For example, you could specify that your

```
<%= render partial: "contact_info", layout: "users/show" %>
```

This would tell the `contact_info` partial to render inside a layout found in `app/layouts/users/show.html.erb`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but not quite what I meant. I'll post it later.

Comment: Sure, I'm actually kind of curious about what kind of solution you came up with.